# Duplicating pandas dataframe vertically

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
    Month  Day   season
0       4   15  current
1       4   16  current
2       4   17  current
3       4   18  current
4       4   19  current
5       4   20  current
```

I would like to duplicate it like so:

```
    Month  Day   season
0       4   15  current
1       4   16  current
2       4   17  current
3       4   18  current
4       4   19  current
5       4   20  current
6       4   15  past
7       4   16  past
8       4   17  past
9       4   18  past
10       4   19  past
11       4   20  past
```

I can duplicate it using:

```
 df.append([df]*2,ignore_index=True)
```

However, how do I duplicate so that the `season` column has `past` as the duplicated values instead of `current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a good case for `assign` since it allows you to keep your functional programming style (i approve!)

```
In [144]:  df.append([df.assign(season='past')]*2,ignore_index=True)
Out[144]:
    Month  Day   season
0       4   15  current
1       4   16  current
2       4   17  current
3       4   18  current
4       4   19  current
5       4   20  current
6       4   15     past
7       4   16     past
8       4   17     past
9       4   18     past
10      4   19     past
11      4   20     past
12      4   15     past
13      4   16     past
14      4   17     past
15      4   18     past
16      4   19     past
17      4   20     past
```